# Using Quartz to create a cron express for a task to run every 2 weeks on Thursday and Friday

Tags: quartz.net

Not sure if this can be done. The task would run every 2 weeks on Thursday and Friday for all months. I don't see anything exactly like this in Quartz.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that this can't be done in Quartz.